# How to configure tcpdump to read udp from 4G not from Wi-fi

Tags: android, interface, tcpdump

I want tcpdump to listen to a port to receive UDP packets so I use the classic

```
tcpdump -i lo udp port 5353 -vv -X
```

But the prompt ends the activity right after without any output.
I think this has to do with the `lo` interface only being used for Wi-fi while I'm using my phone 4G internet. Is this the case? If so then what is the interface name that I should use?

Comment: `tcpdump -D` will show you the available interfaces. You can try to be more verbose with `tcpdump -vvv`. Do you see any traffic without a capture filter?

Comment: well the D option displays three interfaces: lo, any and nfqueue. I'll try the vvv and I don't see any traffic at all

Comment: Make sure that you are root